# How to move a line from a file to the other file on the basis of pattern matching?

Tags: text-processing, grep, regular-expression

I want to move lines from a text file into another text file. Those lines contain a word beginning with an underscore. This word is located on the *sixth* field of the lines; fields are separated with forward slashes. For example, move lines containing `_Nokia` on the sixth field, in the sample input file, below.

```
Apple/One-plus/Samsung/Mi/Sony/_Nokia/
Apple/One-plus/Samsung/Mi/Lenovo/_Nokia/
Apple/One-plus/Samsung/Mi/HTC/OPPO/
```

I have tried to move corresponding lines, with a regular expression, using `grep`, but it does not work.

```
$ grep -F 'Apple/One-plus/Samsung/Mi/^[a-zA-Z]([\w -]*[a-zA-Z])?$/_Nokia/' match.txt >file1.txt
$ grep -F -v "Apple/One-plus/Samsung/Mi/^[a-zA-Z]([\w -]*[a-zA-Z])?$/_Nokia/" match.txt \
    > match.txt.tmp && mv match.txt.tmp match
```

**Expected output**

```
$ cat file1.txt
Apple/One-plus/Samsung/Mi/Sony/_Nokia/
Apple/One-plus/Samsung/Mi/Lenovo/_Nokia/
$ cat match
Apple/One-plus/Samsung/Mi/HTC/OPPO/
```

How to move a line from a file to the other file on the basis of pattern matching?

Comment: Thank you @Fólkvangr for your suggestion, I am new here so I am not aware of rules but apologies for confusing you here. I have updated my question

Answer (score 1):

### Original issue

A regular expression cannot be specified with the `-F` option concerning `grep`. There is another issue concerning the regular expression. If the character `^` is used as an anchor to match the beginning of a line, then, it must be the first character of the regular expression.

```
prompt% cp -v input input.back
prompt% grep -e "$regex" input.back > output
prompt% grep -v "$regex" input.back > input
```

**Regular expression:** the original poster did not provide a concrete input, therefore, it is difficult to find a suitable regular expression.

**Edit:** finally, the original poster has provided a sample input file.

```
Apple/One-plus/Samsung/Mi/Sony/_Nokia/
Apple/One-plus/Samsung/Mi/Lenovo/_Nokia/
Apple/One-plus/Samsung/Mi/HTC/OPPO/
```

**Regular expression:** `regex`

```
regex='\([-[:alpha:]]\+\/\)\{5\}_Nokia\/'
```

### Alternative solutions

These similar solutions are not recommended for beginners whom have never read the sed manual.

```
sed -n "/$regex/p;/$regex/d;w input" input.back > output
```

Roughly speaking, the lines matching the regular expression are saved in the file `output`, then, they are deleted from the corresponding sed buffer and the buffer content is written in the file `input`.

```
sed -i.back -e "/$regex/w output" -e "/$regex/d" input
```

These commands have subtle differences but the second one is more convenient.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a suitably recent version of GNU awk (`gawk`) you could do

```
awk -i inplace -F'/' '$7 == "_f" {print > "otherfile"; next} 1' file
```

If your awk doesn't support the `-i inplace` option, then you can do the same thing but redirect the output to a temporary file and then rename it.

Comment: what's the point of the `next` there? it's not a useless usage for single block?

Comment: @αғsнιη the `next` is what turns it from a copy to a move (i.e. it prints to otherfile, but skips the default print to the original file)

Answer (score 0):

How about this proposition? This is a less concise proposition than [@steeldriver's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/467418/286944), nonetheless, it is a progressive solution (step by step).

```
$ cut -d/ -f7 data.txt  | grep -n _f | cut -d: -f 1 | xargs -i sed -n {}p data.txt > otherfile.txt
```

- `_f` is the pattern when matched is created to the other file.
- `data.txt` is your file
- `/` is your delimiter

If this worked, then do a `comm` to work out what should remain in the original file.

```
$ comm -23 data.txt otherfile.txt > remainder.txt
```

remainder.txt is your data.txt with the bits removed.

Comment: Thanks @Rui first part is working fine as per the requirement but second command $ comm -1 data.txt otherfile.txt > remainder.txt is not working as per the requirement basically it is only creating new file with out moving data from original file.

Comment: Doesnt  remainder.txt have the contents of what you want? If so, then rename remainder.txt to be data.txt and you have your solution, no?

Comment: no, remainder.txt is containing the same data as otherfile.txt. I have tried comm -23 otherfile.txt data.txt but no luck.

Comment: My mistake... comm -23 is what you want. I have edited the answer. Order of the files makes a difference.

Comment: As in comm -23 otherfile.txt data.txt  will not give you what you want BUT
 comm -23 data.txt otherfile.txt  will give you what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can first move the intended lines to the other file (outemp.txt) by:

```
sed -n  '/_/w outemp.txt' input_file
```

then remove those lines from your input_file by:

```
sed  -i '/_/d' input_file
```

check the result:

```
cat outemp.txt 
Apple/One-plus/Samsung/Mi/Sony/_Nokia/
Apple/One-plus/Samsung/Mi/Lenovo/_Nokia/

cat input_file
Apple/One-plus/Samsung/Mi/HTC/OPPO/
```